# Why does the 'address of' operator give me a differant pointer address than the pointer itself?

Tags: c, pointers

For instance:

```
printf("&num_ptr = %p ; num_ptr  = %p ;", &num_ptr , num_ptr);
```

Outputs the following:

```
&num_ptr = 0018FF50 ; num_ptr  = 0018FF48 ;
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the pointer is not pointing at itself.